# Display computer information for all computers in AD

Tags: powershell

Hi i've got a script that gets computer information. I have placed defined the different get values within a variable. And then created a hashtable where i call upon different properties within the variables. This part works fine for a single computer.

I want to get these information for all computer within the domain, but don't know how?

I've been thinking that you could define a variable that contains all AD computers, and then use a foreach statement to cycle through them, but can't get it to work.

How can i output this information information for all computers within the AD, anybody got any pointers?

Thanks in advance

```
$System =Get-WmiObject WIN32_ComputerSystem  
$OS = Get-CimInstance WIN32_OperatingSystem 
$Core = Get-WmiObject win32_processor 
$GPU = Get-WmiObject WIN32_VideoController  
$Disk = get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk 

$ADComps = Get-ADComputer -Filter * 

foreach($i in $ADComps){
 $hashtable = @{  
   CPU_Cores = $Core.NumberOfCores 
   CPU_Model = $Core.Caption 
   Ram = $System.TotalPhysicalMemory 
   GPU = $GPU.Caption 
   OSD = $OS.InstallDate 
   OS =  $OS.Caption 
   Model = $System.Model 
   Computer_Producent = $System.Manufacturer 
   Computer_Name = $System.Name 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-WmiObject` and `Get-CimInstance` only queries the WMI service on *one* machine at a time, so you need to repeat the calls for each machine:

```
$ADComps = Get-ADComputer -Filter * 

foreach($Comp in $ADComps){
  $System = Get-WmiObject WIN32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Comp.DNSHostName
  $OS = Get-CimInstance WIN32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Comp.DNSHostName
  $Core = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $Comp.DNSHostName
  $GPU = Get-WmiObject WIN32_VideoController -ComputerName $Comp.DNSHostName
  $Disk = get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $Comp.DNSHostName

  $hashtable = @{  
    CPU_Cores = $Core.NumberOfCores 
    CPU_Model = $Core.Caption 
    Ram = $System.TotalPhysicalMemory 
    GPU = $GPU.Caption 
    OSD = $OS.InstallDate 
    OS =  $OS.Caption 
    Model = $System.Model 
    Computer_Producent = $System.Manufacturer 
    Computer_Name = $System.Name 
  } 
}
```

`Get-WmiObject` defaults to querying to remote machine using RPC, if that's blocked in the network you might want to use `Invoke-Command` to run the queries on the remote machine and then return the resulting object:

```
$ADComps = Get-ADComputer -Filter * 

foreach($Comp in $ADComps){
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Comp.DNSHostName {
    $System = Get-WmiObject WIN32_ComputerSystem
    $OS = Get-CimInstance WIN32_OperatingSystem
    $Core = Get-WmiObject win32_processor
    $GPU = Get-WmiObject WIN32_VideoController
    $Disk = get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk

    $hashtable = @{  
      CPU_Cores = $Core.NumberOfCores 
      CPU_Model = $Core.Caption 
      Ram = $System.TotalPhysicalMemory 
      GPU = $GPU.Caption 
      OSD = $OS.InstallDate 
      OS =  $OS.Caption 
      Model = $System.Model 
      Computer_Producent = $System.Manufacturer 
      Computer_Name = $System.Name 
    }

    return [pscustomobject]$hashtable
  }
}
```